# OpenGL basics : drawing a multi-color square

Tags: opengl, glut

What I want to do is to draw a square where each vertex is supposed to have a different color.
This should lead into a nice gradient within the square.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(((float)(winWidth-redLineWidth))/2.f,((float)(winHeight-redLineWidth))/2.f);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(((float)(winWidth+redLineWidth))/2.f,((float)(winHeight-redLineWidth))/2.f);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(((float)(winWidth+redLineWidth))/2.f,((float)(winHeight+redLineWidth))/2.f);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(((float)(winWidth-redLineWidth))/2.f,((float)(winHeight+redLineWidth))/2.f);
glEnd();
```

Please ignore the variables used.
I get a rectangle painted, but it has a solid color.
Where's the error here?

I'm using GLUT on Mac OS X.

Comment: be careful, "((float)(winWidth-redLineWidth))/2" gives you an integer.
You might want to change "2" into "2.f"

Comment: @Geneotech Thank you man! Those are the mistakes that you carry around for years and never think about ...

Comment: What color is it, by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems unlikely that you've changed this, but you might try to add a `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)` call before your drawing code.  The default behavior should do as you expected though, so the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! I have a minimal example here. With enabling the option it works as it should. Thanks.